# How to write a name change in the existing view?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

There is a class that inherits from TextView

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using  Android.Graphics;

namespace HelloWorld
{
class TodoListItemView:TextView
{
private Paint marginPaint;
private Paint linePaint;
private int paperColor;
private float margin;

public TodoListItemView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int ds): base (context, attrs, ds)
{
    init();
}

public TodoListItemView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
{
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    Resources myResources = Resources;
    marginPaint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
    marginPaint.Color = myResources.GetColor(Resource.Color.notepad_margin);
    linePaint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
    linePaint.Color = myResources.GetColor(Resource.Color.notepad_lines);
    paperColor = myResources.GetColor(Resource.Color.notepad_paper);
    margin = myResources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.notepad_margin);

}

protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

    canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, Height, 0, linePaint);
    canvas.DrawLine(0, Height, Width, Height, linePaint);
    // Нарисуйте кромку
    canvas.DrawLine(margin, 0, margin, Height, marginPaint);
    // Переместите текст в сторону от кромки
    canvas.Save();
    canvas.Translate(margin, 0);
    base.OnDraw(canvas);
    canvas.Restore();
}

}
}
```

is marking todolist_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TodoListItemView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
/>
```

I pointed TodoListItemView, but that name does not work, there was an error opening the markup. There is an example in Java, as well, so there packages, all clear

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.paad.todolist.TodoListItemView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
/>
```

Which name to show me?

Comment: Please only list the language you are interested in getting an answer for.  If you list multiple languages, it can suggest you don't know what you are writing.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the name space like you used on your class, but there's a difference, the namespace need to be on lowercase.

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
class TodoListItemView:TextView
{

...

}
```

and in your axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<helloworld.TodoListItemView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `monodroid` but my guess is that you have to use it like this on the layout:

```
<HelloWorld.TodoListItemView
...
/>
```

I'm assuming that namespace is the same as package on Java.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <HelloWorld.TodoListItemView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    />

Don't work: "Unfortunately, HelloWorld has stopped"